# What is this fender part called and where do I get one?

Tags: fork, fenders

My bike came with this plastic bracket thing that holds the fender to the fork arch. It's very convenient and now I want to buy another one. Unfortunately, I cannot find this part anywhere online, and I don't even know what it's called. I tried searching for obvious things like "fender fork clip" but no results.

Does this thing have an official name? Do you know where I can get one?

[image: this thing]

Comment: That is fairly specific to that fender and, possibly, that fork.  Unless you can get one from the manufacturer, your best bet is to check your local hardware store for a cable clamp (of the type used to attach a wire to a wall) that seems to fit.

Comment: I see possibly 3D printing in your future.... Measure it with calipers, design it in a CAD software, and print it.  Improve the design, print another, and iterate.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the name of that part is "plastic bracket thing that holds the fender to the fork arch". You had that right!

Answer (score 2):

You could try finding the fender online, and then see what parts come with it.

Comment: This is an OEM fender, it's not sold online.

Comment: @DmitriNesteruk my bad...

Comment: Then the parts are presumably specific to that fender and also not sold online. Have you tried asking the shop you bought the bike from?